# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3. 2:compile (default-compile) on project ***: Compilation failure

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I build java project with maven, and after the upgrade from jdk1.7 32bit to jdk1.7 64bit, the build cannot be successful.

The version is:

```
bash-3.1$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_75"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

maven information is:

```
bash-3.1$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07843dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b686bc1X9; 2014-02-15T01:37:5
2+08:00)
Maven home: d:\Dev\Env\apache-maven-3.2.1
Java version: 1.7.0_75, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: d:\Dev\Env\Jdk7
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: GBK
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

but while I build with maven:

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests=true
```

the error is:

```
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#afterRebuildExecution
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.502 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-11T16:46:43+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/163M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
2:compile (default-compile) on project apiserver: Compilation failure -> [Help 1
]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on p
roject apiserver: Compilation failure
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compila
tion failure
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(Abstrac
tCompilerMojo.java:913)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.ja
va:129)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:133)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:208)
        ... 19 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
```

What's the problem? My JDK version is consistent.

Comment: Despite the fact that you just showing an excerpt of the output the problem is located here: ` project apiserver: Compilation failure ` ...Your code has the problem? Check the log output ...there is output regarding the compilation failure.

Comment: Thanks@khmarbaise, I have solved the problem, the reason is that I downloaded the imcomplete JDK7 package.    But it is very strange that the "Maven-Compile-Plugin" does not have a error description. such as "[ERROR]    ", no description

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who reads this, try to double check the env variables of java home and java path.